# Why app crash when receive push notification from firebase in react native?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, react-native-firebase

I am using react-native-firebase for remote push noticification. I am able to recieve noticification when app open or in background. But when I kill the appliction and remove it from memory, once i send message from firestore app crashes in mobile. I followed the complete documentation and implimented as per the documentation. What is the reason of app crash and how I can fix it?

My App.js

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
import type { Notification, NotificationOpen } from 'react-native-firebase';
const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});
export default class App extends Component {
    async componentDidMount() {
        const notificationOpen: NotificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
        if (notificationOpen) {
            const action = notificationOpen.action;
            const notification: Notification = notificationOpen.notification;
            var seen = [];
            alert(JSON.stringify(notification.data, function(key, val) {
                if (val != null && typeof val == "object") {
                    if (seen.indexOf(val) >= 0) {
                        return;
                    }
                    seen.push(val);
                }
                return val;
            }));
        } 
        const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel('test-channel', 'Test Channel', firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max)
                .setDescription('My apps test channel');
// Create the channel
        firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);
        this.notificationDisplayedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationDisplayed((notification: Notification) => {
            // Process your notification as required
            // ANDROID: Remote notifications do not contain the channel ID. You will have to specify this manually if you'd like to re-display the notification.
        });
        this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification: Notification) => {
            // Process your notification as required
            notification
                .android.setChannelId('test-channel')
                .android.setSmallIcon('ic_launcher');
            firebase.notifications()
                .displayNotification(notification);
            
        });
        this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen: NotificationOpen) => {
            // Get the action triggered by the notification being opened
            const action = notificationOpen.action;
            // Get information about the notification that was opened
            const notification: Notification = notificationOpen.notification;
            var seen = [];
            alert(JSON.stringify(notification.data, function(key, val) {
                if (val != null && typeof val == "object") {
                    if (seen.indexOf(val) >= 0) {
                        return;
                    }
                    seen.push(val);
                }
                return val;
            }));
            firebase.notifications().removeDeliveredNotification(notification.notificationId);
            
        });
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
      console.log("unmount called");
        this.notificationDisplayedListener();
        this.notificationListener();
        this.notificationOpenedListener();
    }

    componentWillMount(){
      if (!firebase.apps.length) {
        firebase.initializeApp({
          clientId: 'my client id-',
          appId: 'my app id',
          apiKey: "my api key",
          authDomain: "fcm-auth domain
          databaseURL: "database url
          projectId: "fcm-app-id,
          storageBucket: "fcm-app-BUCKET
          messagingSenderId: "sender id
        });
      }
      firebase.messaging().getToken()
        .then(fcmToken => {
          if (fcmToken) {
          console.log(fcmToken)
          } else {
            console.log("no token")
          } 
      });

      firebase.messaging().hasPermission()
        .then(enabled => {
        if (enabled) {
          // user has permissions
          console.log("user has permission")
        } else {
          // user doesn't have permission
          console.log("user don't has permission")
        } 
  });
    }
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```js
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fcm">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
        <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseInstanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

app/build.gradle

```js
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fcm"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2"
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```